# c syntax in kernel code and its working

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a doubt about a syntax used in linux kernel code. I have an intuition of what it does but I want to know it more formally. I am using kernel `v3.5.4`

In file `/include/linux/sched.h` the following is defined

```
struct task_struct {
    volatile long state;
    //some more data members
};
```

and in file `/include/linux/init_task.h` file the following is defined:

```
#define INIT_TASK(tsk) {
    .state     = 0,               \
    //some more initializations

}
```

I am confused about two things:

a) I feel it is used for initialization but can anyone suggest some good read for this type of initialization for structures.

b) I do not understand how the following initialization works. Like how this `#define` and the corresponding `task_struct` structure are related.

[EDIT]
I noticed the following things also:
c) Is `\` at the end of every line necessary.

d) There are many parts of kernel doe wrapped in `#ifdef #endif`. If you want to initialize a data member wrapped in `#ifdef #endif` can we use this form of initialization. I mean can we use `#ifdef #endif` inside `INIT_TASK()` like this

```
#define INIT_TASK(tsk) {
    .state     = 0,               \

    //some more initializations
    #ifdef CX 
    .tickets   = 5,               \
    #endif

}
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at once. One of the important things of this site is that Q/A should be searchable and useful for others afterwards, and not only for your immediate use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
struct task_struct whatever = INIT_TASK(someTsk);
```

This results in the following code:

```
struct task_struct whatever = { .state = 0 };
```

which is valid C syntax to initialize fields in a struct via their name instead of their position. Doing so makes the code safe against struct members that are not added at the last position.

Regarding the backslashes: Yes, they are necessary so the preprocessor knows that the macro continues on the next line.

No, you cannot use `#ifdef` inside a macro.

Comment: I understood, Just one more doubt: In `INIT_TASK(...)` the `...` is part of syntax or they are substitution for something.

Comment: In this case it was meant to be *something* for `tsk`.

Comment: I have edited the question. It may be unethical to make such modifications but can you please modify your answer as I noticed these after I made the post.

Comment: does that mean that to make give a initial value to my data member I have to modify `copy_process()` function. Will it be sufficient.

Comment: I have no idea and it doesn't belong into this question.